Using PyMySql to connect to RDS from lambda - getting (1045, Access Denied) error
I'm trying to connect to MySQL RDS from lambda using pymysql library but keep getting error:
(1045, "Access denied for user 'user'@'10.224.13.51' (using password: YES)")
I'm using AWS CDK to create the lambda, both the RDS and the lambda are in the same VPC, this is the code that I have in the infrastructure:
// Shared lambda SecurityGroup 
const lambdaSecurityGroup = new SecurityGroup(scope, 'exampleSG', {
  vpc: sharedResources.vpc,
  allowAllOutbound: true,
  description: stackConfig.stackName + '-sg',
  securityGroupName: stackConfig.stackName + '-sg',
});
lambdaSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(lambdaSecurityGroup, Port.tcp(3306));

// RDS SecurityGroup
const rdsSecurityGroup = SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(this, 'RDS-SG', 'sg-id');

// Add an ingress rule to the RDS security group to allow traffic from Lambda security group
rdsSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(lambdaSecurityGroup, Port.tcp(3306), 'Allow Lambda to connect to RDS');  

// get Claims Lambda
this.getClaimsLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'GetClaims', {
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'lambdas/get_claims')),
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_11,
  handler: 'get_claims_lambda.execute',
  logRetention: logs.RetentionDays.ONE_WEEK,
  timeout: Duration.seconds(10),
  description: stackConfig.environmentKey,
  environment: {
    ENVIRONMENT: environmentKey,
    RDS_HOST: secretProvider.getEncryptedSecretVal(stackConfig.rdsSecrets.RDS_HOST, kmsKey),
    USER_NAME: secretProvider.getEncryptedSecretVal(stackConfig.rdsSecrets.USER_NAME, kmsKey),
    PASSWORD: secretProvider.getEncryptedSecretVal(stackConfig.rdsSecrets.PASSWORD, kmsKey),
  },
  tracing: Tracing.ACTIVE, // enable X-ray
  insightsVersion: LambdaInsightsVersion.VERSION_1_0_143_0,
  layers: [lambdaLayer],
  vpc: sharedResources.vpc,
  vpcSubnets: {
    subnets: sharedResources.subnets,
  },
  role: getClaimsLambdaRole,
  securityGroups: [lambdaSecurityGroup]
});

and this is the code used to connect to the RDS:
def get_connection(user_name, password, rds_host, db_name):
    try:    
     return pymysql.connect(host=rds_host, user=user_name, password=password, database=db_name, connect_timeout=5)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("rds_utils: ERROR Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySQL instance.")
        logger.error(e)`

I have tried several stuff there, I verified that the credentials are correct and used them to connect to the RDS from MySQLWorkbench just fine.
I have allowed the connection to the security groups of both the RDS and lambda.
Is there anything else I'm missing?

This is typically a credentials issue. How are you calling get_connection()? Please include the code that reads the environment variables

It looks like your security group at least is properly configured, but the CDK has an easier way to do it:
dbCluster.connections.allowFrom(lambdaFunc, ec2.Port.tcp(3306)); dbCluster.grantConnect(lambdaFunc, "dbUser");
I suspect as Phil noted that it's probably having to do with the secrets you are passing. Make sure they are correct!

@WesleyCheek it's actually even easier than that - dbCluster.connections.allowDefaultPortFrom(lambdaFunc);. You don't need to specify the port - CDK knows it. As for grantConnect - that will only work if you enable IAM auth and create the user manually.

What's secretProvider? Include that code as well.
